# Question about building CAE model with the paper

Tags: model, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

here's the paper I refernece -- https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1474034621000276?casa_token=a-73z8sMNlEAAAAA:8fDbPqa_oMG2NCtlo8UR8AuxalVxEcfZ4bDBPOQ0tYqv_d4aeKdyRpZ8AXrf2uRlpZ17ylZiIT8

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wX9Lq.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QhuF.png)

Above is the structure of the model
But I don't know if I build it in the right way
Below is my code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvp5r.png)

The difference betwwen the paper and mine is the pixel of images
The paper's is 50*50
Mine is 1024*1024
And I don't know how to adjust the parameters

Thanks for the helping

Is my model building in the right way?
If not, then how am I suppose to get it right

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.